# Popup without user action?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

How is this site triggering its popup while bypassing Chrome's pop-up blocker?

http://undertexter.se/

I thought pop-up blockers only allowed window.open if it was triggered by a user action but that's not the case here so how are they doing it?

Comment: I opened the above site using IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. There are no pop-ups at all.

Comment: They simply aren't, but it is very easy to do user action without realizing it since just clicking anywhere on the page is enough already. Simply **just** clicking the link here and staying back doesn't give me any popups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on my own server, This opens up http://google.com in a new (standalone) window in Chromium 28 on Ubuntu 12.04. Adblock is active.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open('http://google.com','...','width=1080 height=640')
})
</script>
```

Comment: The site is gone but I believe this was how they did it. So in other words no pop-up was opened until a click happened (anywhere on the page). This works since many people click for no reason while they are reading stuff etc.

Comment: Glad you find it suitable. And yes and yes, I've seen a lot of sites implementing popups like this. And people (me included) clicks just for the fun of clicking sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

**OUTDATED**
Origin resources and fiddles do not work anymore.

I figured out that there is an popup opening in chrome if you visit the Website first time (empty cache) and click somewhere on the document.
After a refresh and a click on it again nothing will happen if cache wasn't removed.

So lets start the game of reverse engineering...

Took the script from
http://undertexter.se/ and startet refuscation.

After a few steps I got the following code and I think this is not planned by browser manufactures to support something like this.

Now I wish you a lot of luck to use that for your own but I think it's evil.

Look on js fiddle for the result:
Its the reverse of:

```
http://www.wigetmedia.com/tags/undertexter.se.js
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W9BdS/

Comment: @mplungjan Obviously yes. Both links aren't working anymore. Not suprised after 7years

Comment: Can you find the JSFiddle one? It did not disappear, just got renamed and went HTTPS as well

Comment: nope I do not have a jsfiddle account as it was years ago possible to create fiddles without account. Tried to reset wit all my email addresses

Answer (score 0):

try this using JQuery

```
        $('#yourCotrolId').on('click', function() {
    window.open('yourLink','...','width=1080 height=640')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` is blocked by modern browsers when called not in a `click` event handler.

I faced this myself while using Rails' `format.js` responses and wrote [a small plugin](https://github.com/colorfulfool/rails-popup) that makes showing JS popups as simple as calling `window.open()`:

```
Popup("<div>Hello world</div>").show('up')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the .trigger method for simulating an user action:

```
<a href="javascript:" onClick="window.open('example.html','example','width=200,height=200');">Click</a>
$('a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://theandystratton.com/2012/how-to-bypass-google-chromes-javascript-popup-blocker

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't explain how this page is doing it since it opens it without any user action at all.

Answer (score -1):

`.trigger()` can not be used to mimc such native browser events, you can use .`simulate()` from `simulate.js` to mimic such events.

include simulate.js in your file and use,

`$('a').simulate('click')`;